# Replacing specifics spaces for tab

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a big text file with addresses, and I want split the data into 3 variables. Example:

```
NM_LOGRADO

Street BLA BLA BLA 340
Av BLE BLI 318
Road BLI 48 Block 4
```

I want transform into:

```
NM_LOGRADO

Street(TAB)BLA BLA BLA(TAB)340
Av(TAB)BLE BLI(TAB)318
Road(TAB)BLI(TAB)48 Block 4
```

Basically, replace the first space and the last space before the first number space by tab.
I'm using Notepad++, and for the second replacement I tried replace ' (?=[0-9])(?<=)' by '(TAB)', but it replaced all spaces before numbers (in the third line I got `Road(TAB)BLI(TAB)48 Block(TAB)4`). For the first replacement I have no idea :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Search` > `Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   (?:^.+?\K | (?=[0-9]+.+))
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   \t
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press `Replace All`

You can test it with your example at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xQ2aN2).

---

**Update1**:

Based on your updated sample, try this:

Find:

```
    ^([^ ]+) ([^0-9]+) (.+)
```

Replace:

```
    $1\t$2\t$3
```

Test it at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/dO4dR4).

---

**Update2**:

Based on your updated sample, try this:

Find:

```
    (?:^[^ ]+\K |(?<!Block|Ap) (?=[0-9]))
```

Replace:

```
    \t
```

Test it at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/wY6oH7).

Comment: It fails when I have something like `Road BLI 48 Block 4 Ap 5`. I want `Road(TAB)BLI(TAB)48 Block 4 Ap 5`, but returns `Road(TAB)BLI(TAB)48 Block(TAB)4 Ap 5`.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer and it works with the `Ap 5` too. Please take note that none of the answers here, would handle properly the case where the road name (eg `BLI`) would contain a number (real life example (`Rua 24 de Outubro` a street in your home town). If you have such road names, you should process them manually, or you rewrite the regular expression and include a list of available words after the street numbers (`Block`, `Ap` etc).

Comment: Now it fails when I dont have numbers (I know, my examples are awful :/). And thanks for your concern, the data will be revised after the replacement. Solve using 2 rules:  `^([^ ]+) (.*)` for `$1\t$2` and `(.\t)([^0-9\n]*) ([0-9]+.*)` for `$1$2\t$3`

Comment: OK! Updated again. You can see that I'm using `Block|Ap` in the pattern. Add there any other keywords that are mixed with your street numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that (TAB) refers to a tab character rather than a literal string.

**Find what:** `^(\w*) ((([A-Z]{3})( )?)+) (\d.*)$`

**Replace with:** `\1\t\2\t\6`

(If my assumption was incorrect, replace `\t` with `\(TAB\)`)

The key is the ungreedy space: `( )?`. That leaves the leading and trailing spaces uncaptured, and therefore replaced by the tab characters.

Explanation of regular expressions:

`^` Beginning of line
`(\w*)` Any number of alphanumeric characters, i.e. "Street", "Av", "Road"
`((([A-Z]{3})( )?)+)`  3 uppercase letters, followed by an ungreedy space, once or more, i.e. "BLA BLA BLA", "BLE BLI", "BLI"
`(\d.*)` A digit, followed by any number of any characters, i.e. "340", "318", "48 Block 4"
`$` End of line

`\1` First capture group, "(\w*)"
`\t` Tab character
`\2` Second capture group, "((([A-Z]{3})( )?)+)"
`\t` Tab character
`\6` Sixth capture group, "(\d.*)"

Comment: Almost there! I just changed to `^(\w*) ((([^0-9]+)( )?)+) (\d.*)$` (my street names aren't only 3 uppercase letters), but it fails in cases I dont have any number. Sorry for bad examples!

Answer (score 0):

as you're using Notpad++, the easiest way is not to bother with regex but rather use a macro. simply record one and play it until the end of the line. You'll want to:

1. put your cursor at the first character of the file
2. Macros > Start Recording
3. find a space and convert it to tab (this will replace the first space of the row)
4. press END to go to the end of the line
5. use "find previous" command to find the last space of the line
6. replace that space with tab
7. go to the next line
8. Macros > Stop Recording
9. Run your macro till the end of the file